# How to dynamically modify series inputs or variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a modeling for a shiftwork model.

The basic idea is that the number of shifts can be defined by the user. After assigning the shift's number,  there should be the same amount rows be created. Every row(detailed information about the shift) contains the shift's name, how many people works in this shift, shift start time and end time. All of the information in every row will be used for some further calculation.

Can someone give me some pieces of advice about how can I implement this shiftwork model? I just don't know if I should create a class for shiftwork or create a kind of dynamic variables.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider using the `tkinter` module for GUI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what your asking but I hope that this will help you..

There is a built-in module for python name `tkinter`. But coding with it is a bit complicated so I would recommend using a designer.

**Designer for macOS :**

PyGubu : https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu

**Designer for Windows :**

PAGE :http://page.sourceforge.net/

You can choose the tool depending on the platform and design the UI like the image in your question and then generate the python file. Now if you run it you can get the interface.

**For `PyQt` :**

Use PyQt5 designer can be downloaded through pip : `pip install PyQt5Designer`
And then add it to path after installing and type `designer-qt5` to run it

Link : https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5Designer/

Comment: Hi Roshan, thanks for your answer. I'm restricted to program the GUI with PyQT and without any designer.  I just have no idea how to build this model behind the GUI. Even though, thanks a lot.

Comment: @WJPING The designers listed above are for `tkinter` not `PyQt`. If you want a designer for PyQt then use PyQt designer

Comment: @WJPING I have edited the answer, Please consider reading the edited part and tell your opinion.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I didn't clarify my question clearly. But creating a GUI is really not the first task in my case. I only want to find how to build the model for the shift work.

Comment: @WJPING Unfortunately, these type of questions shouldn't be asked here.